# Manytomany relation in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm working in Laravel and need help with database relations. I have three tables:

**projects:**

```
+------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(191)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url        | varchar(191)                   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated    | bigint(20) unsigned            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | enum('adobe','invision','pdf') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| preview_id | int(10) unsigned               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**users:**

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email          | varchar(150)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password       | varchar(179)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| remember_token | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**projects_users**

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| project_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Situation: There are several projects, and multiple users can work on multiple projects (ManyToMany).
I need to select (SELECT-statement) all users working on project with e.g ID 1.
How would I do that in plain SQL, and how would I do that in Laravel code (without a raw-sql-query function).

I already looked [here](http://Eloquent:%20Relationships) but I ain't really catching it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$users = User::whereHas('projects', function($q) use($projectId) {
    $q->where('id', $projectId);
})->get();
```

Comment: Error: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found"

Comment: @O'Niel since you're using `User` class, you should add `use App\User;` at the top of the controller.

Comment: Did that and: "Class 'App\User' not found"

Comment: When I use App\Models\User, I get this error: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `projects` inner join `projects_users` on `projects`.`id` = `projects_users`.`project_id` where `users`.`id` = `projects_users`.`user_id` and `id` = 6))

"

Comment: That's because you're using `id` in the pivot table.

Comment: So this is the correct code? $users = User::whereHas('projects', function($q) use($id) {
    $q->where('projects_users.id', $id);
})->get();

Answer (score -1):

```
class Project extends Model{
 public function users()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'projects_users');
 }
}

class User extends Model{
 public function projects()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'projects_users');
 }
}
$project = Project::find(1);
$project->users //list of all the users
```

Comment: Explain your answer more! I already found this code on the internet... Are these classes present it a specific file? Where to code this? ..?

Comment: you have to generate model for the Project and User class artisan command to generate model is php artisan make:model Project and after that same for the User and attach the model to database table by adding the protected $table = 'projects'; to the class and the last to line for accessing the model in the controllers